# Contribution page - the field labels are missing

Tags: contribution-page

I have installed civicrm and created a new contribution page. But the field labels are missing. Below is the link:

http://ny.missionaryfamiliesofchrist.us/index.php/donate

I would appreciate any help to fix this.

Ron

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Please try again... the page loads slow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are there, however, your label text is white on a white background.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will check on this. So I need to change the text color to something darker.

Comment: Yes, you need to change the label text color.